# NoMethodError: undefined method `redirected_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe MachineGamesController do
  describe 'GET search' do
    it 'blah blah' do`
      get :search, name: 'some_machine_games'
      expect(response).to be_redirected_to(machine_game_path('some_machine_games'))
    end
  end
```

The above is an rspec i use to test the controller. It is also placed in the /spec/controllers/ directory. I am getting a

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `redirected_to?' for #<ActionController::TestResponse:0x007fce065ba640>
```

Does any one know why ?

Answer (score 3):

I think is because the matcher **be_redirected_to** does not exist in Rspec.  Try doing this:

```
response.should redirect_to(machine_game_path('some_machine_games'))
```

Comment: if i try should i get the following error undefined method `should' for #<RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationTarget:0x007ff983ad1a90>

Comment: Interesting...Try this: expect(response).to redirect_to(machine_game_path('some_machine_games'))

Comment: Expected response to be a <:redirect>, but was <200> is what i get now. Is there something i am doing wrong?

Comment: hmm. just to double-check, what's in your Gemfile?

Comment: # Gems used by tests and development.
group :test, :development do
  gem 'roll_out', '~> 1.4'
  gem "rspec-rails", '~> 2.12'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.2'
end

Answer (score 1):

redirected_to is not an rspec matcher. You need to rewrite that:

```
describe MachineGamesController do
  describe 'GET search' do
    it 'blah blah' do
     get(:search, name: 'some_machine_games').should redirect_to(machine_game_path('some_machine_games'))
    end
  end
end
```

end

Comment: undefined method `should' for #<RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationTarget:0x007ff983ad1a90>  is what i get

Comment: I see you must have tried expect(response).to redirect_to(machine_game_path('some_machine_games')) as Nobita suggested. In order to help you with your 'was <200>' failure, you will have to show us the search method in your MachineGamesController